# Angular:Show 1 component on click of 2 different components

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 3 independent components

```
Comp1
Comp2
Comp3
```

Onclick of `Comp1`, `Comp2` is shown and to achieve this show/hide functionality I have used `*ngIf` on `Comp2`.

Now I want to show `Comp2` onclick of `Comp3` as well, I know I can achieve this with `*ngIf`. But `Comp2` already has `*ngIf` coming from `Comp1`, so until and unless `Comp1` does not send any flag `Comp2` will not be visible even if I try to show `Comp2` from `Comp3`. The solution to this problem is to use `*ngIf` with `||` operator. But the problem will be if Comp3 sets Comp2 flag as true then onlick of Comp1, flag on Comp2 will already be true only.

I am not able to figure out how to show the same component on click of 2 different buttons on different components.

Please help me with the logic, not the code just logic will help.

Comment: You can use a shared service variable between component 1 and 3. And then you can toggle the shared variable by comp1 and comp3. And use that variable for *ngIf. No need to maintain 2 variables.

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of shared service between this components,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ComponentService {

  private isComponent1Clicked = false;
  private showComponent2 = new Subject<boolean>();
  showComponent2$ = this.showComponent2.asObservable();

  showComponent2(component: string) {
    if(component==='component1') 
    {
     isComponent1Clicked= true;
     this.showComponent2.next(true);
    }
    if(isComponent1Clicked && component==='component1')
       this.showComponent2.next(true);
  }
}
```

Now make use of this service in all three component.

```
export class ComponentOne {
   constructor(private componentService : ComponentService ) {
   }
   onClick()
   {
     this.componentService.showComponent2('component1');
   }
}


export class ComponentThree {
   constructor(private componentService : ComponentService ) {
   }
   onClick()
   {
     this.componentService.showComponent2('component2');
   }
}

//this parent for all three component
export class ComponentParent implements OnInit  {
   showMe:boolean = false; 
   constructor(private componentService : ComponentService ) {
   }
    ngOnInit() {
      this.componentService.showComponent2$.subscribe(data=> this.showMe = data); 
   }
}
```

in html file

```
   <component2 *ngIf= "showMe">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not so clear for me how these components interact each other, but I think you can just use the same variable (or the same function) associate to the ng-click of comp1 and comp3.

```
function showOrHide (flag) {
    flag =! flag
}
```

In this way every time you click on comp1 or comp2 the value of the flag will change